# jQuery click action stripped out by sorting function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, onclicklistener

I have a function, including the following code:

```
$(list).append(item);
$(list).html(
    $(list).children("li").sort(function (a, b) {
      return $(a).val() - $(b).val();
    }));
$(item).click(this.listClick);
```

(Basically, it is creating a `<ul> <li>` from an array of items, including a `listClick` function which fires when any of the list items are clicked, and then sorting the list according to the `li value`).

If I strip out the `sort` function from the script, then it works fine (as in, the list is compiled, with click-function working perfectly, albeit not in the correct order). However, if I sort the list, it strips out the click-functionality (i..e. clicking the items doesn't perform the `listClick` function).

Why is this being stripped out? It doesn't seem to matter whether I place the sort function before or after the `listClick` line is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because you are using `html` method which replaces html content of the element and has nothing to do with the `sort` method. The old elements are removed and their attached event handlers too.  You should either use event delegation or better use `appendTo` instead of `html`:

```
 $(list).children("li").sort(function (a, b) {
      return $(a).text() - $(b).text();
 }).appendTo(list);
```

As the `appendTo` only *moves* elements, the event handlers are preserved.

Also note that `li` element doesn't have `value` property so `.val()` method returns an `undefined` value. You should use `text` method for getting `textContent` of the element. And if `list` is already a jQuery object there is no need to wrap it with jQuery constructor.

Comment: Ah! I only just picked up on the html method - thanks for the headsup! (The value property on the li has already been set elsewhere, but thank you for the advice anyway).

Comment: @user1259798 You are welcome! (I meant only form elements have `value` property.)